# Do any of python's built in modules use threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, standard-library

Will importing/using any of python's built in libraries spawn threads without being explicitly asked?

Comment: Creating a thread on import should be rare; import-time side-effects are usually frowned upon.  However, it appears that `import tkinter` creates a new thread on my OS X machine.

Comment: And of course, `import antigravity` starts a new *process*!  (Provided your web browser isn't already running.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module and [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) module both spawn `threading.Thead` objects internally to help handle I/O with the processes they spawn.

Specifically, `multiprocessing.Pool` [spawns three threads](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f83adc06f486/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l170) as soon as you instantiate it:

```
class Pool(object):
    ''' 
    Class which supports an async version of the `apply()` builtin
    '''
    Process = Process

    def __init__(self, processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(),
                 maxtasksperchild=None):

       ... # Stuff we don't care about
       self._worker_handler = threading.Thread(
            target=Pool._handle_workers,
            args=(self, )
            )   
        self._worker_handler.daemon = True
        self._worker_handler._state = RUN 
        self._worker_handler.start()


        self._task_handler = threading.Thread(
            target=Pool._handle_tasks,
            args=(self._taskqueue, self._quick_put, self._outqueue, self._pool)
            )   
        self._task_handler.daemon = True
        self._task_handler._state = RUN 
        self._task_handler.start()

        self._result_handler = threading.Thread(
            target=Pool._handle_results,
            args=(self._outqueue, self._quick_get, self._cache)
            )   
        self._result_handler.daemon = True
        self._result_handler._state = RUN 
        self._result_handler.start()
```

`subprocess` spawns threads [when you call `popen_object.communicate`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f83adc06f486/Lib/subprocess.py#l1186), to read the stdout/stderr from the running subprocess.

```
def _communicate(self, input):
    stdout = None # Return
    stderr = None # Return

    if self.stdout:
        stdout = [] 
        stdout_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._readerthread,
                                         args=(self.stdout, stdout))
        stdout_thread.setDaemon(True)
        stdout_thread.start()
    if self.stderr:
        stderr = [] 
        stderr_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._readerthread,
                                         args=(self.stderr, stderr))
        stderr_thread.setDaemon(True)
        stderr_thread.start()
```

**Edit**

[Mark Dickinson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830449/do-any-of-pythons-built-in-modules-use-threads/24830551?noredirect=1#comment38551479_24830551) that `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` also spawns a thread, for reasons similar to that `multiprocessing.Pool` (handling I/O with the spawn processes):

```
def _start_queue_management_thread(self):
    # When the executor gets lost, the weakref callback will wake up
    # the queue management thread.
    def weakref_cb(_, q=self._result_queue):
        q.put(None)
    if self._queue_management_thread is None:
        # Start the processes so that their sentinels are known.
        self._adjust_process_count()
        self._queue_management_thread = threading.Thread(
                target=_queue_management_worker,
                args=(weakref.ref(self, weakref_cb),
                      self._processes,
                      self._pending_work_items,
                      self._work_ids,
                      self._call_queue,
                      self._result_queue))
        self._queue_management_thread.daemon = True
        self._queue_management_thread.start()
```

Comment: For Python 3, `concurrent.futures` and `asyncio` probably deserve a mention.

Comment: @MarkDickinson As far as I know, with `concurrent.futures` you're always explicitly asking for a thread (e.g. using `ThreadExecutor`). I don't think `asyncio` creates any threads; it just has the ability to integrate with `concurrent.futures.ThreadExecutor`. The OP specifically was looking for places where threads are used when you don't explicitly ask.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on how "explicit" is explicit.  One slightly hidden case with `concurrent.futures` is creating a `ProcessPoolExecutor`: the first time you submit a job to it, you'll get a couple of extra threads in your main process (thanks to the same `multiprocessing` mechanisms you already identified, so perhaps this doesn't count).  Agreed about `asyncio`.

Comment: Hmm, no; I'm wrong.  At least one of the `ProcessPoolExecutor` threads is being created directly, and not as a result of use of `multiprocessing`.  Not sure whether the other one is coming from.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah, the `ProcessPoolExecutor` point is a good one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The following modules import `threading`, an indication that "threads" could be used(whether implicitly or explicitly)

1. `asyncio`
2. `decimal`
3. `functools`
4. `cookiejar`
5. `multiprocessing`
6. `queue`
7. `sched`
8. `subprocess`
9. `telnetlib`
10. `tempfile`
11. `trace`

---

**The Methodology**

```
grep -r "thread" * | grep "import" | grep -v "test" | grep -v "Lib/threading"
```

In the `{python install path}/Lib` directory.

The methodology used was to see if the "thread" appeared in grep results, and processing the result using a series of `grep`s.

So take this answer with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Yeah, most of those are just importing it to get synchronization primitives. I think the only one actually spawning a thread that wasn't covered in my answer is `telnetlib`, which uses `thread.start_new_thread` instead of the `threading` module. But it only does it if you explicitly ask, by using `mt_interact` (meaning multi-threaded interact).